# Area of a part of a cylinder contained in a ball

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How can one calculate area of the part of a cylinder $x^2+y^2=r^2$ which is contained inside this ball : $(x-r)^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 4r^2$?

I've read a little about surface integrals, but I don't know how and if to apply it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite cylinder can be parametrized by
$$(\phi,z)\mapsto (r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi, z)\qquad(-\pi\leq\phi\leq\pi, \ -\infty<z<\infty)\ .$$
The condition $(x-r)^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4r^2$ puts a bound on the length of the stalk  erected on the point $(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi,0)$:
$$(r\cos\phi-r)^2+r^2\sin^2\phi +z^2\leq 4r^2\ ,$$
or
$$z^2\leq 2r^2(1+\cos\phi)=4r^2\cos^2{\phi\over2}\ .$$
It follows that this stalk ranges from $z=-2r\cos{\phi\over2}$ to $z=2r\cos{\phi\over2}$, so that the intended part $S$ of the cylinder has the parametric representation
$$(\phi,z)\mapsto (r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi, z)\qquad(-\pi\leq\phi\leq\pi, \ -2r\cos{\phi\over2}<z<2r\cos{\phi\over2})\ .$$
It follows that
$${\rm area}(S)=\int_{\hat S} r\>{\rm d}(\phi,z)=r\int_{-\pi}^\pi 4r\cos{\phi\over2}\ d\phi=16r^2\ .$$

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the stalk?

Comment: @hagrid: The infinite cylinder is a union of vertical lines through the points $(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,0)$, called stalks in the above. These stalks are cut off at $z=\pm 2r\cos{\phi\over2}$ by the condition $(x-r)^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4r^2$.